# How can I add two new tablets to my Google Play Store account?

Tags: google-play-store, google-account

I have my mobile added already, but I bought my kids a tablet each and I can't find a way to add them to the Google Play Store account so I can download games onto the tablets. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want all devices under one account. All tablets and devices must be under one Google account. So whatever e-mail you use personally on your mobile, use that same e-mail/Google account for your kids' device.

**Example**: If your e-mail, let's say, for example is dad123@gmail.com, all devices must be connected to that Google e-mail account. So use the e-mail you use Google with, for your kids too.

Comment: Further to the answer, create a restricted profile in your tablets (standard feature from android 4.2) for the kids with your account as admin. This will help you to prevent in-app purchases being made by your kids accidentally.